# Forum Software Recommendations for Story Based Content

Tags: forum, phpbb

I've been wanting to start a forum for writing stories for some time now. This week I have been looking at various forum softwares deciding which will ultimately provide the features I'm looking for. No single piece of software will meet all my needs as far as I can tell, so I'll have to develop (or contract out) plugins. That being said I have some questions for anyone that might know:

I love the look, style, and organization of F95Zone.to. When I think of what I would like, many of the feature ideas come from elements I've seen there. I can't seem to figure out what forum software it's using, however. If I were to guess, it's PHPBB, but honestly I would not know how to confirm this. It would be valuable because it gives me an idea of what's possible with the software.

Key features I need are these:

1. Rating of posts in certain forums (i.e. only able to rate stories) I
   really like the review tab F95Zone has for it's games. That would be
   incredible on a story forum.
2. Tagging system with search (stories only). Ideally only admins could
   make tags, but users could apply from the predefined list.
3. Only Authors can post in the stories forums.
4. Disable quoting initial post.
5. I would like to make it so users can't quote a story, because lets
   face it, some yahoos will and that makes the comment section crazy
   bloated.
6. Post templates for specific forums to simplify making news posts
   providing clarity of what's required.
7. 
8. Advanced formatting of posts for stories: I want the stories to be novel formatted only on story forums:
9. All text Justified like novels in story forums
10. First line of every paragraph indented
11. Patreon links on Author profiles so they can gain support for their
    writing.

This is what I have mapped out so far. Please, if you have any insight, I'd love to hear it.